# stack checking html tag balance in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem where I'm trying to use a stack to check if an html file has balanced tags. I have the program working with C++ file. It checks if the brackets are balanced. The problem is the tags like  is to big the fit in a char. I'm getting an error too many characters in character constant. Is there a way around his?

```
bool balanced(char A[], int n) {
int i;

stack <char> a;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    if (A[i] == '<head>' || A[i] == '<title>' || A[i] == '<body>') {
        a.push(A[i]);
    }
    else
    {

        switch (A[i]) {

        case '</head>':

            a.top();
            a.pop();

            break;
        case '</title>':

            a.top();
            a.pop();

            break;
        case '</body>':

            a.top();
            a.pop();

            break;



        }


    }



}
```

Comment: Please read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: Simplify your life, use a tested html parsing library.  Search [softwarerecs.se] before posting there.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this

```
A[i] == '<head>'
```

A[i] is a character not a string. You should be using std::string. If 'A' were a string you could do

```
A =="<head>"
```

or use strcmp (not idiomatic c++)